# Correct JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Is this correct json format?

```
{
    "count": {
        "hbase": 66,
        "java": 63,
        "spring": 41,
        "Sample": 39,
        "minify": 36,
        "TS-WS1": 28,
        "jprofiler": 26,
        "logging": 24,
        "SCM": 24,
        "csrfguard": 20,
        "ldap": 19,
        "hadoop": 18,
        "jquery": 18,
        "android": 17,
        "TS-WS2": 17,
        "myplace": 16,
        "jvm": 16,
        "daily": 15,
        "oops": 15,
        "node.js": 15,
        "long": 15,
        "css3": 13,
        "html5": 13,
        "jms": 13,
        "ci": 11,
        "node": 11,
        "backlog": 11,
        "jsf": 10,
        "groovy": 10,
        "outofmemory": 9,
        "adf": 9,
        "Exception": 9,
        "guidelines": 9,
        "abc": 9,
        "liferay": 8,
        "performance": 7,
        "Groovy": 7,
        "jenkin": 7,
        "Hadoop": 6,
        "Learning": 6,
        "code": 6,
        "design": 6,
        "CTT4TL": 6,
        "": 6,
        "eclipse": 5,
        "templates": 5,
        "apache": 5,
        "Node.JS": 5,
        "analytics": 5,
        "cap": 4,
        "CSRFGuard": 4,
        "corba": 4,
        "pattern": 4,
        "EST-WS1": 4,
        "web": 4,
        "formatter": 4,
        "Minify": 4,
        "guava": 3,
        "oracle": 3,
        "security": 3,
        "checklists": 3,
        "lda": 3,
        "ana": 3,
        "bi": 3,
        "ctt4tl": 3,
        "est-ws2": 3,
        "exception": 3,
        "EST-WS2": 3,
        "oop": 3,
        "how": 3,
        "hibernate": 3,
        "LDAP": 2,
        "cxf": 2,
        "Scala": 2,
        "interceptor": 2,
        "hudson": 2,
        "jenkins": 2,
        "sonar": 2,
        "viva": 2,
        "nfr": 2,
        "java7": 2,
        "CSS3": 2,
        "jpa": 2,
        "ppt": 2,
        "Hudson": 2,
        "template": 2,
        "des-ws3": 2,
        "Hadoop\/HBase": 1,
        "secur": 1,
        "csrf": 1,
        "DB": 1,
        "university": 1,
        "abcd": 1,
        "jsa": 1,
        "LOGGING": 1,
        "json": 1,
        "rm": 1,
        "TS-SCM": 1,
        "nak": 1,
        "fad": 1,
        "presentation": 1,
        "est-ws1": 1,
        "terna": 1,
        "lucene": 1,
        "coding": 1,
        "log4j": 1,
        "JPA": 1,
        "theme": 1,
        "training": 1,
        "secu": 1,
        "build": 1,
        "css": 1,
        "project": 1,
        "solr": 1,
        "DES-WS": 1,
        "intercep": 1,
        "test": 1
    },
    "date": MonMay0612: 19: 48IST2013
}
```

I receive this JSON on one of my ajax call. And just after receiving it shows "parserror".
My code -

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: jsonURL + SEARCH_HISTORY_JSON + EXT_JSON,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json",
       async : false,
       success: function(data) {
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         /*  $("#tagCloud").html(getMessage(tagcloud.error));
           $("#searchHistory").hide();*/
           alert(status);
           console.log(status);
       }
});
```

Also please tell me how to access this data. Should I access it like data.data and data.count?

Comment: This is what you need http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: And the value after "date" is wrong, it should be quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Parse error on line 121:
...    },    "date": MonMay0612: 19: 48IS
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

http://jsonlint.com/

You need to put your date like this -

```
"date": "MonMay0612: 19: 48IST2013"
```

Comment: strange...because I created it using JSON-simple library like this -
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("date", formattedDate);
        json.put("count",sortedWords);

Comment: writeFile(configBundle.getString("log.searches.count.file"), json.toJSONString());

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on the "date" field.
You should treat date fields as strings.

Also, I would recommend using UNIX time for that purpose, because it is easier to parse from javascript.

In the success function, you can access the "count" field like `data.count`.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsonlint.com/

> Parse error on line 121:
>   ...    },    "date": MonMay0612: 19: 48IS
>   ---------------------^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

A very easy way to lint your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Change your date format as following:

```
"date":"Mon May 06 12:19:48 IST 2013"
```

& follow the json online editor.i.e. chrome : http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the `date` field.

Please pass `date` filed value with `"MonMay0612: 19: 48IST2013"`