# How To Render Correct JSON format with raised error

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm sure I have a basic `rescue_from` question here but, I am trying to get a desired output when an exception is raised when my `Validation` fails but I can't seem to figure it out.

Currently my `ApplicationController` is as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |e|
  render json: {error: e.message}, status: 404
  end  

end
```

and the JSON output I get is:

```
    {
  "error": "Validation failed: Organization can't be blank, Description can't be blank, Artwork can't be blank, Language code can't be blank, Copyright can't be blank, Right to left is not included in     the list, Digital audio is not included in the list, Portion is not included in the list, Electronic text is not included in the list, Old is not included in the list, New is not included in the list"
}
```

The desired ouput I would like to get (or something similar) is as follows:

```
    {
  "organization_id": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "description": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "artwork": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "language_code": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "copyright": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "right_to_left": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ],
  "digital_audio": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ],
  "portion": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ],
  "electronic_text": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ],
  "old": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ],
  "new": [
    "is not included in the list"
  ]
}
```

I am not sure how to get this. I get the desired output when I comment out the `rescue_from` method in the `ApplicationController` and set the my `RecordController` create method like this:

```
  def create
    r = Record.create(record_params)
    r.save
    if r.save
    render json: r
    else
      render json: r.errors
    end
  end
```

Although this is what I want, I would have to go to every controller and add this but this would not be a DRY method... I would rather centralize this in the `ApplicationController`

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

I have checked [Correct JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393734/correct-json-format) & [How can I “Pretty” format my JSON output in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out after more research.

The exception object `e` in that rescue_from body has a `record` attribute with the record that caused the exception, you can use the `errors` attribute of that record to extract the errors and create a response with the format you want:

I edited this line in `ApplicationController` to:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |e|
  render json: {error: {RecordInvalid: e.record.errors}}, status: 406
end
```

Change `RecordController` create method to:

```
def create
    r = Record.create!(record_params)
    render json: r
end
```

Which will give the output:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "RecordInvalid": {
      "organization_id": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "name": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "description": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "artwork": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "language_code": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "copyright": [
        "can't be blank"
      ],
      "right_to_left": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ],
      "digital_audio": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ],
      "portion": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ],
      "electronic_text": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ],
      "old": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ],
      "new": [
        "is not included in the list"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This really helps if you have other exceptions raised you would like to render exemple:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  render json: {error: {RecordNotFound: "Record not found for id: #{params[:id]}. Maybe deleted?"}}, status: 404    
end
```

with this if I search an invalid record `44` it will render:

```
{
 "error": {
    "RecordNotFound": "Record not found for id: 44. Maybe deleted?"
  }
}
```

I hope this answer helps others!  cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
def create
  r = Record.create(record_params)
  if r.save
    render json: r.to_json
  else
    render json: errors: r.errors, status: 422
  end
end
```

If and error is returned, it will return this:

```
{
  errors:
    {
      attr_1:["can't be blank"],
      attr_2:["can't be blank"]
    }
}
```

Related to the first example you showed, ruby's Exception#message http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html#method-i-message returns the errors in the way you described. I generally see `rescue_from` being used to return generic 404 pages.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying to prevent myself from having to add code to every controller and action. With your method, I would have to do this. This is the reason I want to add code only to `ApplicationController`

Comment: Yea, without trying to parse the Exceptions message, I'm not sure how you would get the same format as is returned on the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, the accepted answer is not the [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/format/#error-objects) specification for errors.

View the linked spec above as there are a few different keys that can be returned with the error object

```
{
 "error": {
    "title": "RecordNotFound",
    "detail": "Record not found for id: 44. Maybe deleted?"
  }
}
```